# How to find paths in the graph with strong links?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

I have a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ which is not necessarily fully connected, where $V,E$ denote vertices and edges of $G$. 
Also an adjacency matrix $A$ represents the weights of directed edges in $G$, i.e. $a_{ij}$ means the weight of the edge from verice $i$ to $j$ and $a_{ij}$ is real number in range $[0~1]$.

Assuming each $a_{ij} \leq 1$, i'm interested in finding paths in $G$ for which the average weight of the path is close to $1$. In other words, the path includes edges with weights close to $1$.

Instead of doing a loop(s) of brute-force search in $G$, is there any systematic way to handle this problem?

Also, should i choose the path length $k$ in advance?

Comment: Note that if no path length is given, a trivial solution is any edge with weight $a_{ij}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with linear programming:

Define binary variables $x_{ij}$ that take value $1$ if edge $(i,j)$ is used in the path and solve the following optimization problem :
$$
 \mbox{Min }\; z
$$
subject to:

\begin{align}
&sink_i+\sum_{j}x_{ij} = \sum_{j}x_{ji} + source_i\quad &\forall i\in V\\
&z \ge \varepsilon_{ij}\quad &\forall i,j\in V \\
& x_{ij}- \varepsilon_{ij} \le a_{ij}x_{ij}  \quad &\forall i,j\in V \\
&\sum_{i} source_i =1  \\
&\sum_{i} sink_i =1 \\
&\varepsilon_{ij} \ge 0 \quad &\forall i,j\in V \\
&source_i, sink_i \in \{0,1\} \quad &\forall i\in V
\end{align}

The first set of constraints are flow balance constraints (what goes in must go out). 
With the third constraint, you impose that the difference between the weight of an edge $(i,j)$ on a path and $1$  is bounded by $\varepsilon_{ij}$.
The second constraint defines $z=\max\{\varepsilon_{ij}\}$.
And since you minimize $z$, you should end up with a path with weights close to $1$.

As an example, if edge $(i,j)$ is not in the path, then $x_{ij}=0$, and the third constraint is :
$$
 0- \varepsilon_{ij} \le 0 
$$
which leads to $\varepsilon_{ij}=0$. If edge $(i,j)$ is in the path, then $x_{ij}=1$, and the third constraint is :
$$
1- \varepsilon_{ij} \le a_{ij}
$$
which bounds the difference between $a_{ij}$ and $1$ by $\varepsilon_{ij}$.

If you need a specific path length $k$, it is also easy to handle with this approach (just add $\sum_{i}\sum_{j}x_{ij}\{=,\ge\}k$ in the constraints). Note that without a given path length, a trivial solution is any edge with weight $a_{ij}=1$.

You might (I am not $100\%$ sure) need to add a constraint like 
$$
\sum_{j}x_{ji}\le M(1-source_i) \quad \forall i \in V
$$
to make sure that no unit of flow enters the source. And similarly with the sink, you don't want any edges of the path starting from the sink:
$$
\sum_{j}x_{ij}\le M(1-sink_i) \quad \forall i \in V
$$

Comment: and what about $b_i$?

Comment: $b_i=0$ for all nodes, except for the the source and sink, where it equals $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: in fact, i want each $a_{ij}$ which is in the path to be close to 1, or maybe we can also say it as "the path weight should be equal to {path steps}".

Comment: Yes, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: does it mean that i have to decide on $b_i$ in advance? like having to solve the above for each couple of vertices $\{v_i,v_j\}$ as the predefined source and sink?

Comment: Indeed, if your source and sink are not defined, you can solve the above for each couple of vertices, or slightly modify the balance flow constraints. I will edit to show you how.

Comment: I tried it and worked, thank you! But still interested in efficiently solving the whole problem (finding all paths of different lengths but avoiding subset paths). I'd be happy if you can send me an email, or if i can contact you to discuss it in more detail! :-)

Comment: Did you receive my e-mail?

Comment: Yes i did, and working on that:)